# Iterate through all objects in Jframe

Tags: swing, jframe, loops

I have a simple question. I have a project made with javax.swing.JFrame. I would like to iterate through all the objects that i Have added in the Jframe. Is that possible, how can I do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this will iterate through all components inside your JFrame's contentPane and print them to the console:

```
public void listAllComponentsIn(Container parent)
{
    for (Component c : parent.getComponents())
    {
        System.out.println(c.toString());

        if (c instanceof Container)
            listAllComponentsIn((Container)c);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame jframe = new JFrame();

    /* ... */

    listAllComponentsIn(jframe.getContentPane());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works. What is weird is that I cant do anything with these components. Inside the for loop i have this condition: if(c instanceof JTextField){          
          JTextField j= (JTextField)c;
          System.out.println(j);
          j.setText("ABCD");
       } It prints the tostring of j but doesnt set the text, any ideas?

Comment: *"any ideas?"*  1) Ask another (new) question. 2) Add an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Explain the use-case, the need, for this unusual requirement. 4) Ensure the update is made on the EDT.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will clear all JTextFields in a JFrame using a FOR loop

```
Component component = null; // Stores a Component

Container myContainer;
myContainer = this.getContentPane();
Component myCA[] = myContainer.getComponents();

for (int i=0; i<myCA.length; i++) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, myCA[i].getClass()); // can be removed
  if(myCA[i] instanceof JTextField) {
    JTextField tempTf = (JTextField) myCA[i];
    tempTf.setText("");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An iterative way of traversing all components from a "root" component and "do something" (consumer) with them:

```
public static void traverseComponentTree( Component root, Consumer<Component> consumer ) {
    Stack<Component> stack = new Stack<>();
    stack.push( root );
    while ( !stack.isEmpty() ) {
        Component current = stack.pop();
        consumer.accept( current ); // Do something with the current component
        if ( current instanceof Container ) {
            for ( Component child : ( (Container) current ).getComponents() ) {
                stack.add( child );
            }
        }
    }
}
```