# Change background color of components with reference to Color variable java

Tags: java, swing, colors, background, components

I am trying to create a JFrame with numerous JPanels and sections of text, all of which have default colors (panels have background of white, and text is black). I would like to allow the user to change these dynamically at run time, so I have implemented a JColorChooser dialog, where I can click on a button, have the Dialog display, and from there I am able to save the Color.

My default colors are set up in instance variables, as so:

```
private Color panelColor;
private Color textColor;
```

To set the background color of my panels, I use:

```
JPanel samplePanel = new JPanel();
samplePanel.setBackground(panelColor); //panelColor has already been instantiated
```

This works fine, making the panel white. However when I try to use the JColorChooser to load a new Color for use, the panels do not change. The code I use after a Color is selected is:

```
if(newColor != null)
{
    panelColor = newColor;
    myFrame.repaint();
}
```

All my Components are inside a single JFrame, and I thought that calling repaint() on the JFrame would in turn call paintChildren() and cascade all the way down to the lowest level.

I believe that my issue lies in my understanding of how objects are handled in Java. I know that objects are passed-by-reference, but I am also assuming that when I set the background color of the Components, this is achieved through a pass-by-reference scenario, which I'm beginning to doubt. When I call setBackground(), does the Color parameter that I pass in end up as a copy through pass-by-value?

If my hunch is correct, does this mean I should just write up a method that has all the components that require their backgrounds to be changed, and call setBackground() of each, passing in the Color variable with the new value?

Cheers

Comment: Yes, you probably need to call `setBackground()` on each object.  Or use transparent (non-opaque) components and just set the background of their parent panel, but transparency can be tricky.  Some objects rely on opaqueness to erase their viewports properly.

Comment: Hmmm, in that case it seems like it might be best to call setBackground() of each component, even if it is going to take a while. I'll avoid messing with the transparency solution, I have quite a busy UI, so it is likely I could make a mess of it quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the fact that the Color object is passed-by-value to the Component when using setBackground(), as markspace suggested, each Component will have its individual method called.

Using a modified version of the code provided by Dan O in this thread: [Iterate through all objects in Jframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271116/iterate-through-all-objects-in-jframe),
 I have come up with a solution that will allow modification of each JPanel within a JFrame (or any Container for that matter). It is a recursive solution, so any nested Container instances will also have their children iterated through.

```
public void setPanelColor(Container parent)
{
    for(Component c : parent.getComponents())
    {
        if(c instanceof Container)
        {
            if(c instanceof JPanel)
            {
                c.setBackground(panelColor);
            }

            setPanelColor((Container)c);
        }
    }
}
```

As I am using an instance variable (panelColor) to hold the Color, I can reference it from within the method, but you could easily pass it in as a parameter and substitute panelColor for the name of the passed in Color variable.